# Why am i getting this Drush error after updating a site?

Tags: drush, updating

I use Drush 8.1.17 to update my Drupal 7 sites, and as I have been updating my sites today after the latest security update I have noticed that after I update a site if I try to run any update related command (ex: drush up -n | grep available) I get this error:

```
The external command could not be executed due to an application error.                                      [error]
The command could not be executed successfully (returned: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught                         [error]
TYPO3\PharStreamWrapper\Exception: Unexpected file extension in "phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/.." in
/srv/www/htdocs/fac-dev/misc/typo3/drupal-security/PharExtensionInterceptor.php:39
Stack trace:
#0 /srv/www/htdocs/fac-dev/misc/typo3/phar-stream-wrapper/src/Behavior.php(72):
Drupal\Core\Security\PharExtensionInterceptor->assert('phar:///usr/loc...', 'url_stat')
#1 /srv/www/htdocs/fac-dev/misc/typo3/phar-stream-wrapper/src/Manager.php(83):
TYPO3\PharStreamWrapper\Behavior->assert('phar:///usr/loc...', 'url_stat')
#2 /srv/www/htdocs/fac-dev/misc/typo3/phar-stream-wrapper/src/PharStreamWrapper.php(412):
TYPO3\PharStreamWrapper\Manager->assert('phar:///usr/loc...', 'url_stat')
#3 /srv/www/htdocs/fac-dev/misc/typo3/phar-stream-wrapper/src/PharStreamWrapper.php(401):
TYPO3\PharStreamWrapper\PharStreamWrapper->assert('phar:///usr/loc...', 'url_stat')
#4 [internal function]: TYPO3\PharStreamWrapper\PharStreamWrapper->url_stat('phar:///usr/loc...', 2)
#5 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/filesyste in
/srv/www/htdocs/fac-dev/misc/typo3/drupal-security/PharExtensionInterceptor.php on line 39
, code: 255)
pm-updatestatus failed.
```

Does anyone know why this error only appeared after I updated the site and how I can fix it?

Comment: I only read `typo3`???

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Wow, there really is TYPO3 in Drupal: https://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/misc/typo3/phar-stream-wrapper/README.md?id=7f1f3b8

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bug report for the core project, and covered by the latest core releases

Answer (score 2):

It looks like they just released Drupal 7.63 and in the release notes they say, "This is a hotfix release for a regression affecting some Drush installations that was introduced by the fix for SA-CORE-2019-002. No other fixes are included."

Comment: Ah yeah, see [Drush fatal error after upgrading to 8.6.6, 8.5.9, or 7.62: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TYPO3\PharStreamWrapper\Exception](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3026386).